# jQuery - Copy a dynamic link from one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

The URL in div.alpha is dynamic. I need to take this URL and apply it to an 'a href' that wraps 'View Details' in div.beta

```
<div class="alpha">
    <a href="http://www.url.com">Example</a>
    Plus some other stuff which may contain links, etc
    that I don't want to copy to the other div.
</div>

<div class="beta">
    View Details
</div>
```

Desired result:

```
<div class="alpha">
    <a href="http://www.url.com">Example</a>
    Plus some other stuff which may contain links, etc
    that I don't want to copy to the other div.
</div>

<div class="beta">
    <a href="http://www.url.com">View Details</a>
</div>
```

I can get the link like this: `$('.alpha').find('a').attr('href');`

But I don't know how to pass that link to the XXXX below:

```
$('.beta').each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace('View Details', '<a href="XXXX">View Details</a>'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clone `a.alpha`, then just wrap `.b`'s contents with it:

```
// clone the link, remove the text
$link = $('.alpha').find('a').clone().text('');

// wrap all .beta's contents with the cloned link
$('.beta').contents().wrap($link);
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdydrsyo/)

Comment: What happens when you have multiple div.alpha & div.beta in a loop? It's using the first .alpha link for all the .beta links

Comment: @seanuk there are many ways of doing it, but doing it the best way largely depends on your markup. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/fdydrsyo/3/) of how to do it when `.alpha` and `.beta` have a common parent

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the result by updating your code to following.

```
var href = $('.alpha').find('a').attr('href'); // get href of anchor
var text = $('.beta').text(); // get text of beta element i.e. View Details
var betaHTML = "<a href='" + href + "'>" + text + "</a>"; // Create anchor
$('.beta').html(betaHTML); // Update beta element
```

Comment: will this work if .alpha also contains other HTML that I don't want in .beta?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $betaAnchor = $('.alpha a').clone(); //clone anchor
var anchorLabel = $beta.text(); //grab text from beta tag
$('.beta').append($betaAnchor.text(anchorLabel)); //append cloned anchor with beta text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have several `div.alpha` and `div.beta` elements then the best way to achieve this -- it also works for a single pair -- is:

```
$('div.beta').html(function(i,html) {
    return $(this).prev('div.alpha').find('a').clone().html( html );
});
```

```js
    $('div.beta').html(function(i,html) {
        return $(this).prev('div.alpha').find('a').clone().html( html );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pair">
  <div class="alpha">
    <a href="http://www.url.com">Example 1</a>
  </div>

  <div class="beta">
    View Details
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pair">
  <div class="alpha">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Example 2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="beta">
    View Details
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery - Copy a dynamic link from one element to another**

```
CopyLink = jQuery('.page-id-269 ').find('a').clone().attr('href');
jQuery("#menu-item-387 a").attr("href", CopyLink);
```

**Best solution 100% Work**